# Icons force TPopupMenu to OwnerDraw?

Tags: delphi-7, vcl, delphi

I assigned some icons to a TPopUpMenu but it looks like it changed to ownerdraw (it's set to false)...
I also use the XP Manifest but it still looks so old (Win2000 Style)... Is it possible make it look like in windows/explorer? Maybe a component?

Here's an image displaying the problem:

[image: Delphi 7 Popup with Images (Themed)]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does "assigned some icons" mean? `TPopupMenu` accepts images from a `TImageList`; is that what you're referring to? It also doesn't require `OwnerDraw`, even in Delphi 7. Can you post an image that shows the problem you're trying to solve, and more details about how you're doing things now?  Thanks.

Comment: I see the problem. I've edited to add an image to demonstrate. I created this by using the standard D7 included icons, added an `TImageList` and a `TPopupMenu` to a new application's main form, assigning the imagelist to the popupmenu, and setting some random imageindex values to some new menu items, and dropped a`TXPManifest` on the form to add theme support. You're right - the drawing is terrible, but it's not owner-draw. It's just extremely outdated Delphi 7.

Comment: thank you very much for editing. It's not ownerdraw but it really looks like it :/

Comment: @Ken Owner draw is exactly right. When you attempt to include images alongside menu text then the VCL passes `MFT_OWNERDRAW` to the Win32 menu API `InsertMenuItem`. This is still the case in today's Delphi. It's not owner draw in the sense that the programmer has to draw it, but it's owner draw in the sense that Windows won't draw the menu and so the VCL does.

Comment: @Ken And today's Delphi still has lots of bugs in its owner draw menus. That's why I modify Menus.pas to avoid owner draw and stick to system drawn menus. It's really tragic because you don't need to use owner draw menus to get glyphs since Vista. And even worse, MS provide sample owner draw Vista menu code that works, but Emba can't seem to translate that from C to Delphi. Sigh.

Comment: @David, thanks for the correction. My mistake in phrasing. Point remains the same, though - D7 is antiquated, and whether 100% of those shortcomings have been corrected or not, modern versions of the VCL are considerably better on current OSes. :-)

Comment: @Ken Terminology is a little confusing. Owner draw usually means that the programmer does the work. In this case that programmer is the Emba folk that write Menus.pas. Modern VCL menus are better it is true. I still wish that Emba would pay more attention to my litany of menu related QC reports. It actually doesn't matter for me since my program never runs their defective code, but it would be nice for all Delphi users to have clean menus.

Comment: @David, true, and the reason for my wording mistake. I was trying to say it wasn't requiring the user to owner-draw, not referring to the VCL itself doing so. Again, thanks for the correction. TB2K helps somewhat, and there are some other third-party menu replacements. It would be nice if the VCL itself was fixed, but with the attention that FM is getting I'm not expecting it soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a problem with Delphi 7 being extremely outdated. It was fantastic at the time it was released, but it's a decade old now and its age is showing.

You might find [Toolbar2000](http://www.jrsoftware.org/tb2k.php) useful. In spite of the name, it includes a really flexible replacement for `TMenu` and `TPopupMenu` functionality that allows you to make your menus look like those in Office 2000. (See the note on the linked page with the bullet item `Office 2000 style menus`, which states:

> Office 2000-style menus
>   There is no clear distinction between menus and toolbars, giving you the utmost in flexibility. Toolbars can contain menus, menu bars can contain buttons, and they can share the same items.

It's been released as freeware (with source), so it's available, and AFAICT it still supports Delphi 7. If it's not, `Toolbar97` (available from the same URL) will provide similar functionality.

Comment: thank you very much. I'm not on the PC right now but can you confirm that is is also UNICODE compatible?

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss, I have no idea (don't have it on this machine), but Delphi 7 isn't Unicode compatible. If you're using it's `TPopupMenu`, `Toolbar2000` will work for you as well. The web site provides info on features and compatiblity; if you can read this, you can get to that site. :-) If you're not using `TPopupMenu` your question is totally incorrect and you should edit it to indicate that fact.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss, I just checked. According to the downloads page (don't let it fool you - the Toolbar2K license indicates it's free now), it's compatible with D2009, which means it has to be Unicode-friendly.

Comment: I tried it and it works. But is there a possibility to use SetWindowTheme in UXTheme? So the popupmenu has the explore style?

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss: Is this a new question? The one I answered was about how to overcome the deficiency in D7's theme support. I don't know what your latest comment is asking.

Comment: Not sure if it's a new question but I wanted the popupmenu to look like a context menu in explorer (explorer theme). I experimented with SetWindowTheme but no luck.

Comment: There is no "explorer theme". I have no idea what it is you're asking here, but it appears to be something new. Please post a **new** question, and post images of what you're getting now and what you want instead.

Comment: No, that's the wrong solution. Post a **new** question. Changing this one after it's been answered makes it look like the answers you've received are wrong or different. StackOverflow isn't about hitting moving targets - if you have a new question, ask a new question.